# Store rest api data without calling a view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api

Ok I have this project that tells me I need to store Rest API data into the database.  Then have endpoints(views) that expose some of the data.  I understand how to consume API data with guzzle just fine.

Here is my problem: how can I store the API data on in the background without calling any routes or anything?  Because I first need to gather the api data, store it in db, then create views that show some of the data.

Is there an artisan command that can run the inputs? I guess I'm just unclear how to call a controller without hitting a view or route?  I hope this makes sense?

here are the directions(I've made the migrations and models but am stuck):

```
Database migrations
Eloquent Models.

Code that connects to and reads from the various JSON endpoints given above.
Code that writes data to the local database

A script (preferable an artisan command) that, when called, will populate pull the data from the endpoints and populate the DB.
```

I do not need someone to completely do this project for me but some direction on what to do would help,  I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Would it just be one big apiController that does all the database inserts then if successful call a view?

Comment: It is a little unclear what your actual problem is, is your problem is you need default data? what is the use case? try to explain a little more.

Comment: The heart of the problem is that I need to store api data into the database separately from the views I'll create later.  In laravel everything is triggered by a route that goes somewhere.  What I need is something like AJAX, something that happens behind the scenes to pull api data and put it in to database.

Comment: ? maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way and I need to trigger that api pull and save code when I do trigger a view? But the last step there "A script that (an artisan command) that when called will populate the database."  That leads me to believe the actions of pulling the api data and saving it to db are separate then calling the views